# More iron = Less remanent magnetic field

Tags: geomagnetism, paleomagnetism, rock-magnetism

I am aware that iron is a magnetic mineral and through the process of thermoremanent magnetization it can store a record to the state of magnetization it formed in.

I wanted to ask if there are any phenomena or explanations to a negative correlation between the iron concentration and the magnetic field, i.e when the iron concentration increases the observed magnetic field from orbit decreases.

Comment: is this question about the change in earths magnetic field and about the on going pole reversal,where does the iron consentration come into the picture and has the consentration changed?

Comment: A source for the claim may help.

Comment: @John related questions by the OP in Space SE: [Possible explanations to a negative correlation between iron (Ferromagnetic) and magnetic field observations from orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44982/12102) and [Possible explanations to Mars' exceptionally strong magnetic anomalies](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45054/12102) though I don't know if that answers your question